# Helpfile does not open to correct context with F1 key

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, helpfile

Using Delphi XE2 and also Delphi 6

I discovered that hitting <kbd>F1</kbd> to open the help file to a help context does not open the help file to the proper context yet using the menu item for which <kbd>F1</kbd> is the shortcut, opens the help file to the proper context. I also have a button that calls the menu item code.

I checked to make sure both <kbd>F1</kbd> and the menu item and the button are calling the exact same line of code and they are:

```
procedure TForm1.Help1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.HelpContext(Self.HelpContext);
end;
```

`Self.HelpContext` value is changed depending on where the user is in the form and I verified that when that line is executed `Self.HelpContext` is the correct value and is the same value when called via <kbd>F1</kbd> or the menu item or the button.

I verified this issue also exists in every previous version of our app written in Delphi 6.

There must be something simple I'm missing here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that <kbd>F1</kbd> gets special treatment by the system. Yes it is true that your menu item's handler that has a shortcut of <kbd>F1</kbd> fires. But after that handler has fired, the app receives a `WM_HELP` message.

This `WM_HELP` message is processed initially by `TCustomForm.WMHelp`. This looks up the help context ID associated with the active control. And then `Application.HelpContext` is called using that help context. And presumably the active control's help context ID differs from that of the form.

So, although your menu item opens the help file at your preferred topic, the subsequent `WM_HELP` overrides the menu item.

It appears that you want all <kbd>F1</kbd> always to route to the form's help context ID. In which case, my advice would be as follows:

- Set the `HelpContext` for the form.
- Remove all `HelpContext` properties for all other controls on your form. In other words, revert them to the default value of `0`.

Then when the `WM_HELP` message is handled, it starts at the active control and find a help context of `0`. Then it will rise up through the parents to the form, which is non-zero.

I think that I would also remove the <kbd>F1</kbd> shortcut from the menu item / action. And let the `WM_HELP` message be the mechanism for invoking help.

Comment: @Sertac Thanks. I'd probably turn it round and stop handling F1 in the menu.
/action. And roll with the WM_HELP.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I really appreciate your help with this and the last help file issue. It turns out a test app with a test help file seems to work. A test with my giant app and the test help file also works! Something seems to not be happy between my giant app and the giant help file.  Removing F1 from the shortcut seemed to have no affect. Even though it does not solve my specific issue I'll accept your answer here because you helped.

Comment: Funny. I reproduced the behaviour that you described.